# Simple Contextual Menu for cocoa app with IB binding

Tags: objective-c, binding, contextmenu, right-click

I' m using a simple context menu on an NSTableView. In order for the right-click to pop it up I' ve used IB bindings and connected the "menu" outlet of NSTableView to my contextMenu instance(NSMenu). (I don't need more complex code to programmatically fill the menu, etc). It seems to work fine, but when I right-click on my NSTableView the xcode's debugger console outputs ...

```
SampleCMPlugIn_Factory( 0x0, 0x289270 )
SampleCMPlugIn_Alloc( 0x28aed0 )
SampleCMPlugIn_QueryInterface( 0x2854f0, 0xbfffe6d4, 0xbfffe758 )
SampleCMPlugIn_AddRef( 0x2854f0 )
SampleCMPlugIn_Release( 0x2854f0 )
SampleCMPlugIn_ExamineContext( 0x2854f0, 0x2410b4, 0xbfffec36 )

Not the Finder!
SampleCMPlugIn_PostMenuCleanup( instance: 0x2854f0 )2010-11-06 04:17:21.722 cocoaZip[40036:a0f]
```

is this normal?
What is it exactly?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a plugin that it was installed behind the scenes on my system by an example Xcode project about contextual menus in Cocoa.